# Javascript to send users screen resolution while body onload

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am about to save users device resolution. But while I want to process info throw javascript it is not founding. My code bellow.

```
<?php
function sar($opt='re', $k=g){
if($k==p){ 
$s=$_POST; }
elseif($k==g){ 
$s=$_GET; }
elseif($k==s){ 
$s=$_SERVER; }
if(isset($s[$opt])){
return $s[$opt]; }
else return 0; }

$head='<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><script>
function showCustomer(){
var width=screen.width
var height=screen.height
var color=screen.colorDepth
var xmlhttp;
if (str==""){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
return;}
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{ xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
else { xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
```

Comment: This is a horrible question however I have provided with a way to detect resolution in form of JS.

Comment: My code is not properly formated. So it is in comment. Please forgive.
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    } }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","isp.php?w="+width+h="+height+c="+color, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); }
    </script></head>
    <body onload="showScreen()">
     <br><div id="result">Info will be listed here...</div></body></html>
';
    if(sar('w')){
    echo sar('w').sar('h').sar('c'); 
    echo $head; }

Comment: Please improve your question so that it is clear. Show your ajax implication. I cannot even make heads and tails of your implication.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect screen resolution with something like this:

```
var h = window.screen.availHeight;
var w = window.screen.availWidth;

console.log("resoution: " + h + " x " + w);
```

Comment: I have get resolution but i am unable to send it to my server with body onload. Can you provide it?